# Stair case remodel staining inconsistent color

Tags: stairs, sanding, stain, treads

I decided to remove the carpet on staircase sanded all the old finished one down completely. Finally got to staining the stair treads. First time doing this big of a project. Used miniwax water based polystain satin. Decided to break into several days. Did every other stair and 2 coats. Those steps look good and some sheen to them. 2 days later I stained the other treads. I thought they looked darker but thought it was just cause they were not dry yet and like an idiot I kept going and did 2 coats like the other steps (because it was the same can of stain it must be right) Well all has dried and the 2nd set are way to dark and completely flat. Possibly I didn't stir good enough the first time and stirred more the second time ughh.. would the color sink to the bottom and poly at the top... really do not want to sand all the stairs again..will do the darker ones but how hard is it to match up the stain now?

Comment: Lesson learned. Always stir well. You might have to sand. Or make the  others darker.

Comment: Different days: different conditions like humidity etc. All in one go, thoroughly stirred etc etc

Comment: What is polystain? Is that a gel stain? Regardless, when finishing wood it is imperative that your technique is consistent. Same stain, same style applicator pad, same application thickness, same wait time before removing excess, same stirring, etc...

Comment: You could scuff up the lighter treads with some 320 sandpaper and do another layer of stain to try and match the darker ones.

Comment: You may consider reviewing the "finishing" tag at the [woodworking.se] sister site. _Loads_ of info there on how to stain and how to recover from a not-so-good staining job.